# How to install devels in linux from compiling source code

Tags: linux, compilation, installation

What is meant by devels/devs of any software/programs/package/library in linux.
How to install devels/devs of any software from compiling source code.

Comment: What do you mean by "devels/devs"? (Developers? Those are people.)

Comment: :), I mean something like libvpx-devel.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Packages suffixed with -dev or -devel contain header files that allow the user to write programs that link against the package's libraries. For example, if you want to write a program that interfaces with libxml2, you'll need to install libxml2-dev to get the appropriate header files.